# How to know the all active branches on different servers?

Tags: git, server, bitbucket

I have multiple servers and we are using Git and bitbucket for manage the versions. Now i want to check which branch is active right now?

I know the tradintional way which is Login into server, git branch etc. but i'm find the easy way for multiple servers on single click or single command.

Comment: what do you mean by "active" branch?

Comment: For example, I have 3 branches
1. 2022/10.1 which has login functionality
2. 2022/10.2 which has forgot password functionality (Stable branch)
3. 2022/10.3 which has forgot username functionality (New Development branch)
Now On the server For testing purposes, I Activated 2022/10.3 in this branch. After done with all my testing I'll change my branch to 2022/10.2 which is a stable branch.

Comment: in case if you running web server on this server, changing branches with git is not a good idea. proper deployment is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one ssh command:

```
ssh SERVER_HOST 'cd APP/DIRECTORY && git branch'
```